# Can't access the response.data from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from the following ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offered-subj/" + $id + '/' + '{{$sid}}',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json', // added data type
      success: function(res) {
        $.each(res.data, function(index, value) {

          $s += `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-check-input me-1" value="${value.id}" type="checkbox" name="course_id[]"
                                    aria-label="...">
                                    <span>${value.ctitle}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <select name="type[]" class="form-select form-select-sm">
                                        <option disabled hidden selected>Select Type</option>
                                        <option value="regular">Regular</option>
                                        <option value="recourse">Recourse</option>
                                        <option vlaue="retake">Retake</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                
                          </li>`;
        });
        // console.log(res.data);
        // // $obj.append($s);
      }
```

It's response with the following data what I found in browser network section.

[image: Sample console]

But the main problem is when I am trying to get the response data using 'res.data' its not appearing. I can't access the 'res.data'

Comment: try using arrow function like this it might work

 success:  (res) => { $.each(res.data, function (index, value) {

Comment: try res.data[0]

Answer (score 0):

`res.data` is the default response content for axios.
Since you also have a `data` wrapper in your response, the way to access it is `response.data.data`